# Create a table in Tableau Public with word wrap on a dimension and a header on a measure shown as text

Tags: tableau-desktop

I want to include a table on a dashboard. I have a product name, a description of that product, and a value:

| Product | Description | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. | 300 |
| B | Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. | 234 |
| C | Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat | 496 |
| D | Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. | 220 |
| E | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. | 105 |
| F | Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget. Id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi. | 602 |
| G | Et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer. Quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod quis. | 549 |
| H | Ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat | 419 |

I expect the table to look something like this:

[image]

This is the closest I've come:

[image]

There are at least two issues:

##### 1. Word wrap

I can't get word wrap to work on the description. I have changed every format setting I could find to word wrap on:

[image]

##### 2. A header for the continuous field

The **Value** header is missing on the continuous field because Tableau seems to want an axis to label.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to it.
actually, you have to **enable** the word wrap and you will then drag the row a little bit below, try doing that and you will see that the text automatically adjusts in your expected format.

For the header, drag measure names to the column pane and measure values to the mark pane text box and then filter the measure names and only select sales (in your case , "Value")

[image: like this]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Adding measure names to the column allowed me to get the header in for Values, but I still can not get word wrapping to work. I have enabled word wrap in every field, column, sheet, header, pane, total, and grand total I can find, and still no wrapping.

Comment: As i said, you need to drag between the lines (rows) and it will adjust itself

Comment: I understand that is standard behavior for word wrap, but it is not adjusting. I slide, and it does not change.

Comment: ok so this is partially solved i guess,

Comment: Yes. I still have no idea why the wrapping isn't working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: feel free to reach out here at the community : https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/debayan.kar